# What is the best way to create a dictionary class in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to store a map of dictionary values at spring bean. This bean should return a message, stored in the mentioned map by code. For example the dictionary with about 11 elements, like:

```
[
    {
        1: "critical case"
    },
    {
        2: "common processing error"
    },
    ...
]
```

and a bean

```
@Component
class ErrorAnalyzer {
    
    fun aggregateErrorDescriptions(errors: List<Int>): String {
         // need to get all code descriptions from dictionary by errors
    }
}
```

I assume, that it is a bad approach to store my dictionary as a static variable in `companion object` of that bean like:

```
companion object {
    private val dictionary = mapOf(
        1 to "critical case",
        2 to "common processing error"
    )
}
```

Perhaps a lazy-loaded map sounds better but i'm not sure that it is much more efficient though...

```
val lazyValue: Map<Int, String> by lazy {
    mapOf(
        1 to "critical case",
        2 to "common processing error"
    )
}
```

Also the lazy map way can be modified by loading from a resource json file, but that's only for 11 elements... Also i have a feeling, that no elements would be added to this map in future...

What is preferrable / your way of this?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what "most efficient" or "best" mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe I didn't understand the question right but if you need this map globally then just create it as a bean, something like this:

```
@Bean
fun nameOfADictionary(): Map<Int, String> = mapOf(...)
```

in a `@Configuration` class and then inject it where you need in the context.

Otherwise, if you only need it somewhere locally, then create the map in a file / class where it'll be used as a private object and that's it. You don't even need the `companion object` feature here.

Also if we talk about 11 elements in a collection, in my opinion, you don't need to mind about performance issues, just use the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.